# Communicating with a php script using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I wrote a simple jQuery function to submit data from a textarea. The script returns the result of the computation.
I get an error saying that recievedData isn't defined.
When debugging with firebug I can see a response.

Here's my jQuery function.

```
$('#submitButton').click(
function(evt){
userCode = $('#answer').val();
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : 'scripts/php/check_answer.php',
data : 'code=' + userCode,
dataType : 'text',
success : alert(recievedData)
});
evt.preventDefault;
});
```

And this is the php script

```
<?php

//sample string, to be taken as input from the user program.
$str = $_POST['code'];
//the array with the weights
$patterns = array (
    '/[:space]/' => 0, //whitespaces are free; need to add spaces too
    '/[a-zA-Z]/' => 10, //characters
    '/[0-9]/'   => 500, //digits
    '/[\+\-\/\*\%]/' => 10000, //arithmetic operators
    '/[\<\>]/' => 5000, //relational operators
    '/[\^\~\|\&]/' => 1000 , //bitwise operators
    '/[\=]/' => 250, //assignment operator
    '[\#]' => 100000 //No Macros
);

//default weight for characters not found is set here
$default_weight = 55;
$weight_total = 0;
foreach ($patterns as $pattern => $weight)
{
  $match_found =  preg_match_all ($pattern, $str, $match);
  if( $match_found )
  {
     $weight_total += $weight * $match_found;
  }
  else
  {
    //this part needs to be fixed
     $weight_total += $default_weight;
  }
}

echo $weight_total;

?>
```

Comment: It's coz recievedData isn't defined. ;-) Side note: if you decide to use that name in your application, I recommend spelling it "receivedData" -- and I'm not being snotty or pedantic; we spelled "received" incorrectly in our application and it haunted us for years! No joke! (Had to do with backwards compatibility)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

```
success:function(data){alert(data);}
```

Comment: That worked, one more doubt. If I wanted to call a named function instead of an anonymous function, what would I need to do?

Comment: Just provide the function name, without inverted commas: `success: successFunction, ...`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to post with jquery

```
$('#submitButton').click(
function(evt){
userCode = $('#answer').val();

$.post("scripts/php/check_answer.php", {code: userCode},
   function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });

evt.preventDefault;
});
```